# Custom headers Next.js middleware client side

Tags: next.js, middleware, request-headers

I would like to set the request headers dynamically based on a cookie in Next.JS middleware. But when testing I only see the custom header on server-side calls and not on my client-side API calls. Does middleware not run on the client side calls?

I've tried this to set the request headers:

// middleware.ts

```
import { NextResponse } from 'next/server';
import type { NextRequest } from 'next/server';

export function middleware(request: NextRequest) {
    const requestHeaders = new Headers(request.headers);
    requestHeaders.set('x-currency', 'test');

    const response = NextResponse.next({
        request: {
            headers: requestHeaders,
        },
    });
    return response;
}
```

Comment: Do you mean it's not visible when inspecting it in the network tab in the browser?

Comment: @yousoumar yes indeed. I do see the custom header in getServersideProps when I console.log it but not in the network tab for client side requests

Answer (score 0):

Middleware runs between and server. It starts after the client request and ends before the server response.